# How to change the QueryString on post back?

Tags: asp.net, postback, query-string

I would like to perform a post back and have several values added to my query string.  I had been using a redirect to the same URL and simply adding query string parameters but when I do this my View State is cleared, which I need to avoid.

Because of the technology I am working with (SharePoint) I have to pass my parameters using the query string.

I did some looking around, but haven't found an clear answer on how to accomplish a post back with different query string parameters.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: A full asp.net postback? no ajax?

Comment: Why not pass all params in the querystring and just rebind the data based on this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by different query string, do you want to just affix some additional params or swop out x for y?

Comment: @izip, I can do this, but I'm saving it for a last resort.  It seems like it would be unnecessarily complex *IF* I can find a way to post back with different query string params.

Comment: @almog.ori - I could need to either add new parameters or change the values of existing parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just messing around, but this adds querystrings clientside by modifing the action attribute of the main form (in this case ct101), before the form gets submitted.
Sample code doesnt take futher postbacks into account..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById('ctl01');

    el.onsubmit = function (evt) {
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        $(this).attr('action', url + '?sayHi=Hi');
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect. The Server.Transfer method also has a second parameter—"preserveForm". If you set this to True, using a statement such as Server.Transfer("WebForm2.aspx", True), the existing query string and any form variables will still be available to the page you are transferring to.

So basically you can transfer to the same page but with newly added query string parameters you will still have access to the old values.

Comment: I was thinking this too, but when I to the Server.Transfer and pass true for the second param I get a Stack Oveflow exception.